# Fixing .NET 2.0 Error

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, .net-2.0

On Window start up with Windows 7x64 I get a .NET 2 error where the system popups a box saying .NET 2.0 is not correctly installed.

I tried downloading .NET 2 framework but the system already has it installed. Tried uninstall and reinstall got nothing.

Is there a way I need to go about fixing it?

Comment: Do you have the detailed error ? Could you also check the eventviewer and look for more details ? (For eventviewer go to Run-->eventvwr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 already includes .net 2.0 (it already has .net 3.5 Sp1 included)! So you can't install .net 2.0 with the MSI installer.

Do you use a Lexmark printer? This message is a known to be causes by older Lexmark printer drivers. Go to the Lexmark site and download the latest drivers:

http://support.lexmark.com/index?page=home&locale=EN&userlocale=EN_US&segment=DOWNLOAD